# C++ code compiled under VS2013 fails to compile under VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Moving a large project from VS2013 (Win7) to VS2015 (Win10). 95% of the project is VB .NET, which I am fluent in, and converts without issue.

Unfortunately there are two small C++ modules, which when I attempt to compile return a large amount of errors which seem to be syntactical :

```
'std::array': too few template arguments<br>
'^':cannot use this indirection on type 'std:array'<br>
left of '->Length' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

The C++ programmer who wrote the original code claims that C++ has changed dramatically from VS2013 to VS2015. I am not a C++ guy so I can't really respond to that. He's pretty busy and not too interested in updating the C++ parts,  suggesting we use VS2013 w/Win10 but I'd rather use at least 2015 if not 2017 for a longer-life span.

Can any C++ guys respond to this? I'm feel that this issue may be in the compiler settings but I'm unsure where to look.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]

Comment: impossible to answer without reproducible code, without which this becomes a fishing expedition

Comment: _"...'^':cannot use this indirection on type 'std:array'..."_ could indicate the original project is C++CLI (dotNET) not pure C++

Comment: What's a "C++ prog"? Did you mean "C++ programmer"? In any case, he's wrong. C++ did not change dramatically from VS2013 to VS2015, and neither did Visual C++. The drastic change in the language was from C++03 to C++11. But it's worse than that: your problem apparently has little to do with C++ language changes, because your question sounds like you never used C++ in the first place but a Frankenstein language called "C++/CLI", which is (was) loosely based on C++.

Comment: Thanks much Richard. Looks like you may have quickly identified the issue. From a quick check, looks like there are numerous differences btwn the dotNet and pure C++ versions. Gives me something to pursue. Thanks again to all who responded.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, I am not a C++ programmer but a little googling got me squared away. There was an incompatibility in managed and standard arrays. Adding

```
#include stdafx.h
#include <array>
```

to two of the modules and changing the array declarations to cli::array did the trick - no compiler errors and calling the C++ dll from VB Net returned the same results as the earlier VS 2013 version.

Thanks again to those who responded.